# Calculate largest differences based on the mean values of grouped columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say I have a simple dataframe like so:

```
  Gene  c1  c2   c3
1    A 500 240    0
2    B 700 235    3
3    C   0 270 1000
4    D   3 100  900
5    E  10 190  830
```

Now what I want to do (in a very big dataset) is find the top 20 columns adhering to the following rules:

1. The value for gene A and B must be as big as possible! AND:
2. All other rows must have a value below a given threshold (lets use threshold of 20). In this case that would include column c1.

```
Gene <- c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "B_3", "C_1", "C_2", "C_3")
c1 <- c(10, 4, 4, 19, 25, 30, 0, 0, 0)
c2 <- c(0, 4, 3, 0, 2, 3, 60, 40, 400)
c3 <- c(1000, 900, 799, 0, 2, 3, 60, 10, 30)
df1 <- data.frame(Gene, c1, c2, c3)
head(df1)

  Gene c1 c2   c3
1  A_1 10  0 1000
2  A_2  4  4  900
3  A_3  4  3  799
4  B_1 19  0    0
5  B_2 25  2    2
6  B_3 30  3    3

tail(df1)

  Gene c1  c2 c3
4  B_1 19   0  0
5  B_2 25   2  2
6  B_3 30   3  3
7  C_1  0  60 60
8  C_2  0  40 10
9  C_3  0 400 30
```

There must be a smart way to do the following:

1. calculate the mean of each of the 3 replicates of "Gene" (so the mean of for example A_1, A_2 and A_3; then also do this for B and C etc). An example would be for c1 and gene A: mean = 6.
2. Taken group A, return the top 20 columns (I know my example dataset only has 3 columns, but my real data has a lot...) that have the **largest** mean difference to group A. Bonus points if there is a way to find the top 20 where group A has the highest mean AND the largest difference with the other groups. I hope this makes sense.
3. It would be best to somehow take the standard deviations of the calculated means into account when calculating the difference to group A (i.e. a large SD means a less accurate difference).

### EDIT AFTER MORE HELP FROM MEL:

I manage to get the means AND standard deviation for each group now. I now have a dataframe that look like this:

```
  Gene  c1_mean  c2_mean   c3_mean ..... c1_sd c2_sd c3_sd
1    A 500       240       0       ..... etc...
2    B 700       235       3       ....
3    C   0       270       1000    ...
4    D   3       100       900     ..
5    E  10       190       830     .
```

Now what I want to do (in a very big dataset) is find the top 20 columns adhering to the following rules:

1. I want to calculate the sum of Gene A and B per column, for c1 that would be 1200, and append a new row that displays this sum. This row we will call "x".
2. I want to find the top 20 columns with the highest value for x. I also want to keep the columns that give the standard deviation of these means as well! This should be easy for someone who is good with R, but these top 20 values ***must*** also follow the third rule! So probably first I should filter out all columns that do not follow it.
3. All other rows (so rows C, D, E etc. This exludes row A, B and "x") must have a value in the "c_mean" columns below a given threshold (lets use threshold of 20). In this case our "top 20"would include only column c1, because it is the only one that sticks to the rules.

Comment: Once you do a mean threre will be only one value per group. So which 20 values are you referring to? Before you do the mean?

Comment: For question 3, I suggest that @MelG's answer is a good start: change to `summarize(across(..., list(mean, sd)))` (column-naming aside). From there, though, it sounds like you want to measure *statistically-significant differences* between groups, for which you should be considering something like a t-test.

Comment: Thanks evans, I indeed managed. Please see the edited changes for the last bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "B_3", 
"C_1", "C_2", "C_3"), c1 = c(10, 4, 4, 19, 25, 30, 0, 0, 0), 
    c2 = c(0, 4, 3, 0, 2, 3, 60, 40, 400), c3 = c(1000, 900, 
    799, 0, 2, 3, 60, 10, 30)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

**Solution**

For questions 1 and 3, I suggest that you use `summarize` to find the mean and standard deviation for the replicates in each gene, following the advice from @r2evans in his comment.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  separate(Gene, c("Gene", "Replicate")) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarize(across(c(c1:c3), list(mean= mean, sd=  sd)))
```

Regarding the second question, you can use `slice_max()` to find the top n number of observations that you desire. I also suggest reading up on how to use `filter` from `dplyr`.

```
df2 %>%
  slice_max(c1, n= 25)
```

Comment: @pleasehelp I did not understand your third question, but if you provide clarification, I cant try to help

Comment: I explained it poorly, but I'll give it another shot:

Comment: Let us take gene group A and find the **top 1** highest mean for A **with** the biggest difference when compared to B and C. This would be column c3, where A has a mean±standard deviation of 899.7±100.5. The difference between the mean of A f(or c3) and B and C is 898 and 866.3 respectively. This difference doesn't take the standard deviations into account however. Is there a way to compensate for that? Because if you for example have a VERY high mean for a given column for A, but it also has a VERY high SD, it is not so valuable to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mel, we are almost there (I managed to get the SD now!). I edited my original post once more to clarify what I want to achieve.